# I'm making a "hangman" game. In the game, I want to add lives and start with 7. Game Over on 0 lives.

Tags: python

Currently this is my code, but i don't know how to integrate the lives concept into my hangman game. When it is Game Over (0 lives), i want the game to end even if they didn't figure out the word after 7 attempts.

```
master = input("Enter a word: ")
print("\n"* 50 )
word = list(master)
length = len(word)
right = list("_" * length)

finished = False

while finished == False:
    guess = input("Guess a letter!")

    if guess not in master:
        print("This letter is not in the word.")

    for letter in word:
        if letter == guess:
            index = word.index(guess)
            right[index] = guess
            word[index] = "_"

    print(right)

    if list(master) == right:
        print("You win!")

        again = input("Again? y/n ")

        if again == "y" or "Y":
            master = input("Enter a word: ")
            print("\n" * 50)
            word = list(master)
            length = len(word)
            right = list("_" * length)
    else:
        finished = True
```

Comment: Okay, cool. So you've got a game loop going. With the 7 lives, you'll want that to persist throughout the loops, right? So think about where you'll be initialising it. Next would be to think when to modify it. It's in one of your if-blocks, for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize a variable with the number of wrong tries allowed and decrement it by 1 every time a wrong entry has been made. Finally check if the number of tries have finished(ie. 0) before continuing the loop.

```
master = input("Enter a word: ")
print("\n"* 50 )
word = list(master)
length = len(word)
right = list("_" * length)
tries=7
finished = False

while finished == False:
    guess = input("Guess a letter!")

    if guess not in master:
        print("This letter is not in the word.")
        tries-=1
        print(tries," tries left")
    for letter in word:
        if letter == guess:
            index = word.index(guess)
            right[index] = guess
            word[index] = "_"

    print(right)

    if list(master) == right:
        print("You win!")

        again = input("Again? y/n ")

        if again == "y" or "Y":
            master = input("Enter a word: ")
            print("\n" * 50)
            word = list(master)
            length = len(word)
            right = list("_" * length)
        else:
            finished = True
    elif tries == 0:
        print("Game Over!")
        finished = True
```